# Django i18n multi-line translate

Tags: django, gettext, django-i18n, po

How to translate the snippet below using django's internalization?

**utils.py**

```
template = _("Below is the result of your WWE Account verification.\n"
             "Thank you!")
```

**django.po**

```
# try
msgid "Below is the result of your WWE Account verification.\nThank you!"
msgstr "A continuación se muestra el resultado de la verificación de su cuenta WWE.\n ¡Gracias!"
```

But when I do the code snippet below...

```
$ python manage.py shell
>>> from django.utils.translation import activate, ugettext_lazy as _
>>> activate('zh-cn')
>>> template = _("Below is the result of your WWE Account verification.\n"
                 "Thank you!")
>>> template
以下是您的 WWE 帐户验证结果。\n谢谢
```

The above outout of `template` is wrong. I expected a new line like below:

```
以下是您的 WWE 帐户验证结果。
谢谢！
```

or

```
Below is the result of your WWE Account verification.
Thank you!
```

**UPDATE 03-29-2022**

- Turns out that I am already correct. I tried `print(template)` and it is working as intended

Comment: Have you tried to print it? Sometimes the REPL doesn't display a string as it would be printed, instead it shows it's raw content.

Comment: Woaahh! Printing worked properly, I will try more!

Comment: I've posted the comment as an answer, if it works don't forget to mark as solved ;D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to print it? Sometimes the REPL doesn't display a string as it would be printed, instead it shows it's raw content.